# How to read and normalize following json in pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have seen many json reading problems in stackoverflow using pandas, but still I could not manage to solve this simple problem.

## Data

```py
{"session_id":{"0":["X061RFWB06K9V"],"1":["5AZ2X2A9BHH5U"]},"unix_timestamp":{"0":[1442503708],"1":[1441353991]},"cities":{"0":["New York NY, Newark NJ"],"1":["New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA"]},"user":{"0":[[{"user_id":2024,"joining_date":"2015-03-22","country":"UK"}]],"1":[[{"user_id":2853,"joining_date":"2015-03-28","country":"DE"}]]}}
```

## My attempt

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

# attempt1
df = pd.read_json('a.json')

# attempt2
with open('a.json') as fi:
    data = json.load(fi)
    df = json_normalize(data,record_path='user',meta=['session_id','unix_timestamp','cities'])

Both of them do not give me the required output.
```

## Required output

```
      session_id unix_timestamp       cities  user_id joining_date country 
0  X061RFWB06K9V     1442503708  New York NY     2024   2015-03-22      UK   
0  X061RFWB06K9V     1442503708    Newark NJ     2024   2015-03-22      UK
```

## Preferred method

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

```
I would love to see implementation of pd.io.json.json_normalize

pandas.io.json.json_normalize(data: Union[Dict, List[Dict]], record_path: Union[str, List, NoneType] = None, meta: Union[str, List, NoneType] = None, meta_prefix: Union[str, NoneType] = None, record_prefix: Union[str, NoneType] = None, errors: Union[str, NoneType] = 'raise', sep: str = '.', max_level: Union[int, NoneType] = None)
```

## Related links

- [Pandas explode list of dictionaries into rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148683/pandas-explode-list-of-dictionaries-into-rows/47149275)
- [How to normalize json correctly by Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091362/how-to-normalize-json-correctly-by-python-pandas)
- [JSON to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
df = pd.read_json(r'C:\path\file.json')
```

---

```
final=df.stack().str[0].unstack()
final=final.assign(cities=final['cities'].str.split(',')).explode('cities')
final=final.assign(**pd.DataFrame(final.pop('user').str[0].tolist()))
print(final)
```

---

```
      session_id unix_timestamp            cities  user_id joining_date  \
0  X061RFWB06K9V     1442503708       New York NY     2024   2015-03-22   
0  X061RFWB06K9V     1442503708         Newark NJ     2024   2015-03-22   
1  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U     1441353991       New York NY     2024   2015-03-22   
1  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U     1441353991    Jersey City NJ     2024   2015-03-22   
1  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U     1441353991   Philadelphia PA     2024   2015-03-22   

  country  
0      UK  
0      UK  
1      UK  
1      UK  
1      UK
```

Comment: why did you choose `cities` and `user` here?

Comment: @Jonnyboi I dont remember very well since it was over a year ago , but by the looks of it, the read_json returned a list for the same session_id and unix_timestamp which we wanted as rows - hence we exploded it. Then we converted the user (which was a list too but we wanted them as columns) to a dataframe and assigned back.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do:

```
import pandas as pd

# lets say d is your json
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T.reset_index(drop=True)

# unlist each element
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[0])

# convert user column to multiple cols
df = pd.concat([df.drop('user', axis=1), df['user'].apply(lambda x: x[0]).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)

      session_id  unix_timestamp  \
0  X061RFWB06K9V      1442503708   
1  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U      1441353991   

                                         cities  user_id joining_date country  
0                        New York NY, Newark NJ     2024   2015-03-22      UK  
1  New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA     2853   2015-03-28      DE
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using `explode` with `join`

```
s=pd.DataFrame(j).apply(lambda x : x.str[0])
s['cities']=s.cities.str.split(',')
s=s.explode('cities')
s.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
s=s.join(pd.DataFrame(sum(s.user.tolist(),[])))
      session_id  unix_timestamp  ... joining_date country
0  X061RFWB06K9V      1442503708  ...   2015-03-22      UK
1  X061RFWB06K9V      1442503708  ...   2015-03-22      UK
2  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U      1441353991  ...   2015-03-28      DE
3  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U      1441353991  ...   2015-03-28      DE
4  5AZ2X2A9BHH5U      1441353991  ...   2015-03-28      DE
[5 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have df, then you can merge two parts:

```py
df = pd.read_json('a.json')
df1 = df.drop('user',axis=1)
df2 = json_normalize(df['user'])

df = df1.merge(df2,left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

just thought i'd share another means of extracting data from nested json into pandas, for future visitors to this question. Each of the columns is extracted before reading into pandas. [jmespath](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py) comes in handy here as it allows for easy traversal of json data :

```
import jmespath
from pprint import pprint
expression = jmespath.compile('''{session_id:session_id.*[],
                                  unix_timestamp : unix_timestamp.*[],
                                  cities:cities.*[],
                                  user_id : user.*[][].user_id,
                                  joining_date : user.*[][].joining_date,
                                  country : user.*[][].country
                              }''')
res = expression.search(data)
pprint(res)

{'cities': ['New York NY, Newark NJ',
            'New York NY, Jersey City NJ, Philadelphia PA'],
 'country': ['UK', 'DE'],
 'joining_date': ['2015-03-22', '2015-03-28'],
 'session_id': ['X061RFWB06K9V', '5AZ2X2A9BHH5U'],
 'unix_timestamp': [1442503708, 1441353991],
 'user_id': [2024, 2853]}
```

Read data into pandas and [split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the cities into individual rows:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(res)
      .assign(cities = lambda x: x.cities.str.split(','))
      .explode('cities')
     )
df

session_id      unix_timestamp  cities       user_id      joining_date  country
0   X061RFWB06K9V   1442503708  New York NY     2024      2015-03-22    UK
0   X061RFWB06K9V   1442503708  Newark NJ       2024      2015-03-22    UK
1   5AZ2X2A9BHH5U   1441353991  New York NY     2853      2015-03-28    DE
1   5AZ2X2A9BHH5U   1441353991  Jersey City NJ  2853      2015-03-28    DE
1   5AZ2X2A9BHH5U   1441353991  Philadelphia PA 2853      2015-03-28    DE
```